# Does Azure Marketplace images have Software Assurance?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-marketplace

Does Azure Marketplace images include with Active Software Assurance or not? For an example, in Azure marketplace "SQL Server 2019 on Windows Server 2019" image comes with Software Assurance or not?

Answer (score 1):

The Software Assurance varies product to product. Many products includes Software Assurance with the product while others have optional purchase.

[image]

I suggest you to go through the official [Microsoft Software Assurance](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/licensing-programs/software-assurance-default). Go through the links/PDFs under **Getting Software Assurance** and **Learn more about Software Assurance** sections.

Also, the same question has been asked and answered on Microsoft Q&A. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/682599/does-azure-marketplace-images-have-software-assura.html).